# Replacing doubles quotes with escape character double quotes in a C string

Tags: c

From a vector, resources (strings) are fetched and some operations are done on the strings later. Out of these, one of the strings (resource) has the following value:

```
"bundle 20B / / <a href="http://ezproxy.rit.edu/login?url=http://firstsearch.oclc.org/fsip?dbname=CWI&done=refer 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456  "
```

But, as this string has a (") double quotes character in it (without \ before it; it is being treated as the end of the string and thus leading to an error at further stage. I want to write a code wherein, if double quotes are detected in the received value from vector, it should be replaced with (\"), so that this error doesn't take place and this process should take place for all the occurrences of double quotes character in that string.

I feel that my solution is not that good. Please suggest some changes in this code to get a better and optimized solution.

```
for(i = 0; i < vector_getCount(resNames); i++)
{
    char *resource = vector_elementAt(resNames, i);
    int size = 0;
    char str[100];
    int i = 0;
    while(resource[size] != '\0')
    {
        if(resource[size] == '\"')
        {
            str[i] = '\\';
            str[i+1] = '\"';
            i = i+2;
        }
        else
        {
               str[i++] = resource[size];
        }
        size++;
    }
    vector_setElementAt(resNames, i, str)
}
```

In this code, this lengthy process will take place for all vector elements. But this would be very bad for performance. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Have you taken into consideration escaped-escape character, such as `\\"` or `\\\\"` ?

Comment: Sorry didn't get you.. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You want to protect your dquote with the escape character -->  ' \" ' . But an escape character can also be escaped --> ' \\ '. So you may end up with something like this ' \\" '. Would the dquote still be safe in that case ?

Comment: @AugustinLopez he aims to escape only `"` character.

Comment: @snr Problem might arise with a string such as `"abc\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to write a simple function making a specified character to do escape. You can toy with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void myEscaper(char const * str_in,
               char * str_out,
               size_t str_out_size,
               char escape_char) {

    size_t length_str = strlen(str_in);
    assert(length_str < str_out_size);
    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length_str; ++i) {
        if (str_in[i] == escape_char) {
            str_out[j] = '\\';
            str_out[++j] = str_in[i];
        }
        else {
            str_out[j] = str_in[i];
        }
        ++j;
    }
    str_out[j] = 0;
}

int main() {
    char const * in = "acdavca";
    char out[100] = {0};
    myEscaper(in, out, sizeof(out), 'a');

    // You can call the below one
    //myEscaper(in, out, sizeof(out), '\"');
    puts(out);
}
```

Comment: I feel like this solution is similar to the one i've mentioned in my question itself,(maybe i'm mistaken) but my issue is that as there is nested loop scenario and there are around 10000 elements in the vector so this inner loop will be called for all those vector elements(strings/resources) which would be bad for performance.I need a better performance solution

Comment: @user2156513 if you find it let me know (: